# elasticsearch return total hits only

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana

i want to send query to ELS that return only the total hits.

without anything else

like if i get the respone

```
{   "took": 1111,   "timed_out": false,   "_shards": {
    "total": 9,
    "successful": 9,
    "failed": 0   },   "hits": {
    "total": 731552,   
 }
```

**i want to print only 731552**

for now i just send :

curl http://server:9200/games_profilder/_search

thanks

Comment: Hi, when I try to do this, I get a limit of 10,000 hits. I don't need all the documents that match my query at once, but I do need to know the total number of matches, not just that its more than 10,000. How do I get around this?

Comment: @Dude use `/_count` endpoint instead of `/_search`

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can use [response filtering](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/common-options.html#common-options-response-filtering) for this:

```
curl http://server:9200/games_profilder/_search?filter_path=hits.total
```

which will yield

```
{
  "hits": {
    "total": 731552
  }
}
```

If you really want to only get the total, you can pipe the result with [`jq`](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/) like this:

```
curl http://server:9200/games_profilder/_search?filter_path=hits.total | jq '.hits.total'
```

and that will yield only the number `731552`

Comment: This is a language agnostic solution directly inside the shell. If you use python, then simply reference the `['hits']['total']` property of your results object.

Comment: This looks great for reducing payload size. For overall efficiency (assuming you need to run this sort of query a lot), does it make sense to _also_ do source filtering? I'm guessing response filters are applied at the very end, and perhaps ES is pulling lots of data into memory only to discard it just before the response is sent. But that's just a guess.

Comment: @ToddMenier Source filtering always helps indeed.