# return only _source data from elasticsearch query

Tags: curl, elasticsearch, elassandra

I want to get only _source fields by the query.but it returns hits which are unnecessary for me.so how to remove this hits before the _source data.

```
GET fms/user/_search?filter_path=hits.hits._source{"query": {"match_all": {}}}
```

[image]

Comment: This answer might help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31569422/elastic-search-exclude-index-and-type-from-json-response/31570789#31570789 (hint: use `filter_path`)

Comment: I'm already using filter_path but I just want the _source portion without the hits and hits

Comment: You are only getting _source field only, it is just that it is wrapped in hits since it is a part of JSON._source is nested json element of hits.

Comment: You can use jq filter..this answer might help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43758813/elasticsearch-return-total-hits-only/43758962#43758962

Answer (score 1):

If you want to filter _source fields, you should consider combining the already existing _source parameter with the filter_path parameter like this:

```
POST /library/book?refresh
{"title": "Book #1", "rating": 200.1}
POST /library/book?refresh
{"title": "Book #2", "rating": 1.7}
POST /library/book?refresh
{"title": "Book #3", "rating": 0.1}
```

> GET
>   /_search?filter_path=hits.hits._source&_source=title&sort=rating:desc

```
{
  "hits" : {
    "hits" : [ {
      "_source":{"title":"Book #1"}
    }, {
      "_source":{"title":"Book #2"}
    }, {
      "_source":{"title":"Book #3"}
    } ]
  }
}
```

For more details, go through at https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/common-options.html

As you are already using filter_path, you are already getting only source field only.